# В чем тут проблема? Синтаксис SASS

Tags: sass

В чем тут проблема?

Пишет Invalid CSS after "rgb": expected selector, was "(33, 41, 49) 2p..."

```css
.doc__img
    margin: 0 auto
    width: 95px
    height: 116px
    box-shadow: rgb(33, 41, 49) 1px 1px,
    rgb(33, 41, 49) 2px 2px,
    rgb(33, 41, 49) 3px 3px,
    rgb(33, 41, 49) 4px 4px,
    rgb(33, 41, 49) 5px 5px,
    rgb(36, 44, 53) 6px 6px,
    rgb(39, 48, 57) 7px 7px,
    rgb(42, 51, 61) 8px 8px,
    rgb(45, 55, 66) 9px 9px;
    background-color: #43a06d
    display: flex
    align-items: center
    justify-content: center
    font-size: 60px
    border-radius: 5px
    border-top-left-radius: 13px
    position: relative
    overflow: hidden
    background: linear-gradient( bottom #000, right #999)
    padding: 45px


.doc__img:before
    content: ''
    position: absolute
    width: 0
    height: 0
    border-top: 15px solid transparent
    border-right: 15px solid rgba(29, 70, 48, 0.75)
    left: -5px
    top: -1px

.pasdpass
    box-shadow: rgb(33, 41, 49) 1px 1px 2px,
    rgb(33, 41, 49) 2px 2px,
    rgb(33, 41, 49) 3px 3px,
    rgb(33, 41, 49) 4px 4px,
    rgb(33, 41, 49) 5px 5px,
    rgb(36, 44, 53) 6px 6px,
    rgb(39, 48, 57) 7px 7px,
    rgb(42, 51, 61) 8px 8px,
    rgb(45, 55, 66) 9px 9px;
    
.shape
//     background-color: rgb(97, 113, 129)
//     height: 150px
//     width: 150px
```

```html
<div class="doc__img">
  <div class="pasdpass">
      lorem
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убери в классах doc__img и pasdpass после последних rgb(...) точку с запятой (;). SASS не подразумевает их использование, поэтому не может скомпилироваться.

Comment: Спасибо бро дошло до меня удачи (еще выручишь ?)